# Get data from settings app to the implementation in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

On my .h:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *user;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *pass;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *mail;

-(void)setValuesFromPrefrences;
```

On my .m:

```
#define kUser @"user"
#define kPass @"pass"
#define kMail @"mail"

- (void)setValuesFromPrefrences {
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSDictionary *initialDefaults=[[NSDictionary alloc]
                                   initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"Username", kUser,
                                   @"Password", kPass,
                                   @"Mail", kMail,
                                   nil];
    [userDefaults registerDefaults: initialDefaults];

    self.user.text = [userDefaults stringForKey:kUser];
    self.pass.text = [userDefaults stringForKey:kPass];
    self.mail.text = [userDefaults stringForKey:kMail];
     }

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self setValuesFromPrefrences];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setTitle:@"FEED"];

    [self refreshStream: @"1" user:@"user" pass:@"pass" mail:@"mail"]; 
}
```

How can I get the values from user, pass and mail to the line:

```
[self refreshStream: @"1" user:@"user" pass:@"pass" mail:@"mail"];
```

Now the code will write the values on labels, and it works - bus I want to use the values in the refreshStream.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. If you want to use the values in the `refreshStream:` method, then why don't just... **do it?**

Comment: I don't want to use the values in the refreshStream - but replace them with values from the settings app (with the fields user, pass and mail).

Comment: What's wrong with `[self refreshStream:[userDefaults stringForKey:kUser]]` etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very confusing because you already seem to know what to do.

Assuming your question is about this line:

```
[self refreshStream: @"1" user:@"user" pass:@"pass" mail:@"mail"];
```

then do what you do inside of the `setValuesFromPreferences` method:

```
NSString *user = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:kUser];
NSString *pass = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:kPass];
NSString *mail = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:kMail];
[self refreshStream: @"1" user:user pass:pass mail:mail];
```

If this isn't what you are looking for them please clarify your question.